# No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina)

Tags: log4j

When I attempt to start up my server and run in browser, the given log has been load in catalina.out. I have used the given log levels in my log4j.properties still the problem is same.

```
log4j.debug=true
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, CATALINA, CONSOLE
```

What can be the solution? Please help me to sort out the problem.

Comment: Is there something missing (given log) in your question ?